# How to make the php code run inside Facebook (as App) hosted in a domain using php SDK?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I have a Facebook page and I want to interact with my viewers using own PHP code. I want the page users to like my page before they can participate any activity posted in my page, such as poll.

Can anyone please guide me / point me how to use PHP Facebook SDK to communicate with my viewers of the page? Also please let me know how I can make them like my page before they participate.

Let me explain differently that I am looking for a definitive guide for **Web site** app and **page tab** app for Facebook using **php Facebook SDK**.

**UPDATED based on reply from JCBiggar**

Thanks for your answers.
I'll separately figure it out how I can get the Facebook user details who is viewing my Tab App. I also need to resolve how can I make them like before they interact with my page. I really don't want anybody to use that page who doesn't like the page.
But lastly I am only confused with respect to my availability of the tab to my viewers. I agree with all your assumptions that I am not looking for publishing my app to Facebook, as it is for my use only. But I want all my viewer to be able to see the Tab page link in my page. Right? That is the basic requirement.
As you told that I need not to submit the same, and as I have already added to Tab to my page it will be available to all my viewer, I tested with a Hello World App but that is the not the case.
I have added

**the view of the page when visited from the other account than owner's account**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-ev9CQ281vyMndWX3NqTi14MGc/edit?usp=sharing

and also added

**the view of the page when visited from the owner's account**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-ev9CQ281vydzltVzNuVEZralE/edit?usp=sharing

As you can see the Tab is only available only when viewed from Owner's account (from the account it was added + the owner of the page), but the same is not available from any other account.
Can you please help me on this and I'll close this question.

I found that I cannot post image, so providing you link separately.

Comment: Aside from any technical issues here, forcing people to "like" your page is counterproductive. Focus on actually *being useful*, and people will organically promote your page.

Comment: @Chris solid, sound advice.  +1

Comment: @ Chris: With my due respect, I understand that I am here to discuss technical feasibility and get to know from expert how to achieve the functionality technically. I am not bothered about the marketing productivity of the said approach. If you know or want to help me technically please do so, else request you to refrain from posting such comments.

Comment: Moderators: I wanted to move the discussion to chat, but currently I am not allowed to do so, hence ended up having long question and answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to do this actually. Well if you are talking about having a "Tab" on your facebook page that has your website, or your php code on there. In order to do this, you will need to have an SSL, for since one of the most recent facebook updates, they require the code you display on their site to be secure.

You will want to check on here for how to create a facebook canvas page. Here is a very good tutorial to do that:

**http://blog.hubspot.com/blog/tabid/6307/bid/26330/How-to-Create-Custom-Tabs-for-Facebook-Business-Pages.aspx**

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you were looking for, but if it is, I know this works, I used to run my whole website through a tab. Hope this helps!

Oh, and not sure if they have to like your page in order to see it. I know a while back that used to be the case. But facebook has had so many updates, I dont know if they have removed that or not.

**Get started on your facebook here:
[developers.facebook.com/apps](http://developers.facebook.com/apps)**

**UPDATED**

You are creating a canvas app. Which can be added on facebook to other facebook pages. Not just yours. But big chances are, people arent going to add a random app that has nothing to do to your page on their page. But since you would like to have php content on your facebook page, this is the only way to do that. The polls app you sent me, the reason that requires people to like their page before they continue, is because the app is not on their page itself. When you create an app. It is given its own app url. So, I am guessing, if you really wanted to, you could add facebook code on your app that you are making, to require them to like your page before they submit, or something. Im not sure of the code to do this.

Now to answer your questions:

The tap app is availible when you add it to your page, any user that gets on your page can see it. And anyone whom your send your url too the app page, can add it to their page... you probably would want to do that anyways, since you just want your code on your page. You would only submit it to the facebook directory if you wanted people to find your app and add it to their pages. But I dont think this is what you are wanting to do.

As far as the secure page. Sadly, the answer is yes, it has to be secure to even test it. I actually found out that facebook update the hard way, when I noticed all my code was just blank each time I was trying to test it. Then later found their update required a SSL Certificate for your page the content is pulling from.

To answer you other questions:

When you add a tab to your page. If someone clicks on the tab. It is still on your facebook page. Its almost like someone clicking on your page photos. It doesnt leave your page, if just show all your photos. The tab is basically the same thing.

Sadly, facebook has remove the option to allow tabs to be the landing page when someone goes to your page. So there is no way Im sure, that I know of, to display the code on your facebook original page.

Now with the adding the tab to your facebook page, let me explain it like this. You know the area where you enter your page tab URL and your secure page tab URL. Well look at that as, telling your app to pull from that page. Which basically displays that page in an iframe on the facebook tab. Now when you go to register. Remember how earlier I said, your page isnt listed in the facebook directory. When this is the way to actually get to your app page: http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&next=YOUR_URL

You are basically entering your UNIQUE APP ID... since many people can use the same URL for different apps, then at the end just page the same URL that you entered for your website field.

This isnt a hack, but just the actually way to get to the page itself. Registering the app, is only if you want to let it show up in the facebook directory, which again, I dont think is something you are really wanting to do. That is mainly for big company's like, lets say, Instagram. I think they created an app, that is in the directory, that users can find and add to thier page, then enter certain information to allow their photos, and stuff to show up. But that is the premise for registering an app. So I wouldnt worry about that, unless the app you are making, you are trying to make for other pages to add for their page.

As of which user is viewing your page tab. I do not know. As far as the coding of facebook apps. I'm not very familiar with. I only used the apps to display my website, and contact forms on facebook pages. It is possible that this displays on your facebook insights for your page. But I am not sure. I do hope this information will be helpful to you, and hope you can figure out what you are trying to do.

**UPDATE:**

So Im not sure why its not viewable for non-admin viewers... Im guessing there might have been another facebook update with that... but I did some research and found something that will solve all your problems.. I dont think you even need a SSL certificate with this:

Watch this Youtube tutorial:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3SWr5wTWsE

And this is the app you can use that is in that tutorial:
https://www.facebook.com/appcenter/static_html_plus

Comment: Thanks the post. But just like other articles this post talks about ways to do so which is outdated / doesn't match one to one with the current settings of the Facebook. I tried such articles, but unable to figure it out. Any recent post which does match with current settings of the Facebook would help. Also I want to know the difference between the Web Site App and Page Tab App. I am more interested in showing the php code inside the business page rather than in a separate tab. Also what about making people like it?

Comment: The tutorial above still works, just somethings are changed about it. Now you need the secure page url. ie `https`... go here to get started making an app: https://developers.facebook.com/apps ... the difference between a website app and page app is, website apps are for you to add to your website. Page Tab apps, are app that you can add as a tab to your page. Facebook no longer allows you to choose a default landing tab, I guess they feel it was abused. But do take another look at the link in my answer, because it does work. And dont forget to approve my answer if it does. Hope I could help.

Comment: `Also what about making people like it? ` ... I just looked to see if you can hide the tab unless people like your page. But facebook has removed that function. Sorry

Comment: Thanks a lot. But there is a way to make people like your page before they can view or interact in your page (Let me say in the Tab opened containing your code) Please see the page https://apps.facebook.com/my-polls/ It is a commercial app where they say Require participants to like your page to participate and increase your fan base. I need to know how to implement the same feature. Also I am working based on the link given by you, I have follow up questions to ask, will consolidate and post soon. Surely once I am done solving my problem I'll accept your answer.

Comment: My understanding, let me know if I am wrong.
1) Well Tab app is just link your webpages with Facebook, nothing to be called as app in traditional sense as it has practically nothing to do with Facebook / it's not native to Facebook.
2) As of now the "Tab App" seems like only available to me (owner) or to test user. So to make it viewable to all the Facebook users who visit my page I need to submit it to Facebook for review make it public.
3) It has to be a secure page even for testing purposes.
4) I got confused cause screens have been changed, but can be figured out.

Comment: @JCBigger I have couple of questions posting as comments one by one as I can not list them all in one go. 1) It is getting opened as new Tab page to the original Facebook page. Is there any way to place it inside the page without adding a separate Tab? I would love to display the same php code in the page itself without the Tab. Any possibilities?

Comment: @JCBigger 2) The way to register the app (as mentioned in the article given by you - Add Your Tab to Your Facebook Page) is like calling a Facebook page by forming URL as specified (which includes dialog) Is this the way to go? or it's a hack? Or Shortcut to some other registration process? I am not convinced that this is the only way or official way to register the app.

Comment: @JCBigger 3) How do I know which Facebook user is viewing my tab page? Let me very clear, say I have a simply form that the user will submit like "Guess a number" and I will read the value in another php file on form submission. If I want to make sure that I accept only one number per Facebook user how do I do so? I guess I can do it by knowing the user id of the Facebook user who submitted the form, can you please let me know how can I get it implemented in "Tab App".

Comment: I updated my answer with answers to all your questions.

Comment: @JCBigger Updated my question based on your answer and also provided the screen shots with the problem description.

Comment: Just updated my answer again.

Comment: @JCBigger The app that you referred is doing the same thing as per the tutorial. It also requires https, anyway I have accepted your answer. If you can figure out why the views were different from different account, please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible. Facebook does nott allow to use your own PHP in your Facebook Page and It should not allow it.

Comment: May be the title of the question was a mistake from my side. I have changed the title line. Sorry for the confusion. I want to interact with Facebook using php Facebook SDK and confused with the types of apps.

Comment: This answer is either misinformed or intentionally misleading. You certainly can create a dynamic Facebook page tab in PHP, hosted on your own server. Read the docs - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/